# not able to handle null value in body in apache camel

Tags: apache-camel

We have replace apache camel fuse project to apache camel(for that did changes in pom.xml),getting error while getting null from database query .
not able to handle null value in body.
earlier it was working in fuse project .

Here is the exception:

```
<data contentType="text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1" contentLength="6579"><![CDATA[org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: java.io.IOException: UT010029: Stream is closed
at org.apache.camel.http.common.HttpMessage.createBody(HttpMessage.java:8`enter code here`0)
at org.apache.camel.impl.MessageSupport.getBody(MessageSupport.java:54)
at org.apache.camel.util.MessageHelper.resetStreamCache(MessageHelper.java:127)
at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.deliverToFailureProcessor(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:1033)
at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:474)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:97)
at org.apache.camel.http.common.CamelServlet.doService(CamelServlet.java:213)
at org.apache.camel.http.common.CamelServlet.service(CamelServlet.java:79)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:584)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:93)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:117)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SendErrorPageHandler.handleRequest(SendErrorPageHandler.java:52)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99)
at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:387)
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:841)
at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2019)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1558)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1423)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Caused by: java.io.IOException: UT010029: Stream is closed
at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletInputStreamImpl.available(ServletInputStreamImpl.java:246)
at org.apache.camel.http.common.HttpConverter.toInputStream(HttpConverter.java:86)
at org.apache.camel.http.common.HttpHelper.readRequestBodyFromServletRequest(HttpHelper.java:193)
at org.apache.camel.http.common.DefaultHttpBinding.parseBody(DefaultHttpBinding.java:595)
at org.apache.camel.http.common.HttpMessage.createBody(HttpMessage.java:78)
... 60 more
]]>

Comment: java.io.IOException: UT010029: Stream is closed
 at org.apache.camel.http.common.HttpMessage.createBody(HttpMessage.java:80)
 at org.apache.camel.impl.MessageSupport.getBody(MessageSupport.java:54)

Comment: Could you please add some of your code to know what's causing it, also a better explanation showing the null value

Comment: i am trying to execute sql query and query returns empty result set that time when i am trying to log body using <log message="${body}">  code break when writting ${body} or if i write method to get body than that method is not getting executed flow breaks before executing that method

Comment: Did you switch stream caching on? Looks like you migrated the route without using stream caching.

Comment: Yes i have used stream cache TRUE in route.

Comment: Please add your route so we can have a context